# $|\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)| $for all reals $x,y$ is it bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ is $$|\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)| $$
bounded?

---

plotted $\arctan(x)$ in [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20arctan%20x)

graphically $|\arctan(x)| < 3 $ so $$ |\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)| < |\arctan(x)|+|\arctan(y)|< 6$$

I do know the highest slope of unit circle is  at angle $\pi /2 $ which seems to be the highest. It is not elegeant using 6. *Not sure how to say it elegangly that it is bounded* Is it just from definion of arctan?

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  The usual definition of $\arctan x$ says that $-\frac {\pi }2 \lt \arctan x \lt \frac {\pi}2$, so it never gets close to $3$ in absolute value.  Now you can use the triangle inequality to get a bound on $|\arctan x - \arctan y|$  Your statement that it is bounded by $6$ is correct, but you can get a lower upper bound.

Comment: Perhaps you should rephrase "lower bound." :)

Comment: @TedShifrin: agreed

Comment: @RossMillikan What about tighter bound?

Comment: @Ed_4434:  it is tighter.  I wanted to echo least upper bound, which can be found here.

Comment: @RossMillikan I just mean.. what about the phrase "tighter bound", rather than "lower upper bound", but I see why you chose to write it that way anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

As $\;\lvert\arctan x\rvert<\dfrac\pi2$, the triangle inequality results in
$$\lvert\arctan x+\arctan y\rvert\le\lvert\arctan x\rvert+\lvert\arctan y\rvert<\pi.$$

Comment: Is it not more correct to write $\lvert \arctan x + \arctan y\rvert \leq \lvert \arctan x\rvert + \lvert \arctan y \rvert$? Just being nitpicky.

Comment: @Ed_4434: You're perfectly right. Don't even know why I wrote this (easier to type?). Thank you for pointing it!

Comment: Not a problem. It's incorrectly written in the question, so perhaps you saw it there hehe

Comment: Probably so.$ $

Answer (score 0):

It is better than bounded: arctan is $1$-Lipschitz, i.e $|\arctan x - \arctan y| \le |x-y|$ for all $x,y$. To see this, show that the absolute-value of the derivative of arctan is uniformly bounded by $1$.